# Приложение на Java для работы с БД

Tags: java

Я новичок в java программировании и совсем недавно начал изучать java. Простые вещи на java понятны (такие как создание классов, условия, циклы, коллекции, циклы). Интересует что нужно изучить для того чтобы написать приложение, которое будет работать с БД (любой)?

Comment: Для начала [JDBC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).

Comment: Первое, что нужно сделать это научиться тщательно искать информацию. Начните с того какие БД существуют, затем поищите уроки по работе с БД из Java. Если в ходе изучения возникнут сложности, то сможете задать более точный вопрос. Почитайте еще [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) в справке.

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать

Comment: автор, а гуглом почему не пользуетесь?

Answer (score 5):

Ответ 3-х уровневый:

1. Первый туповатый уровень - вам надо освоить JDBC - низкоуровневая работа с БД, изучите как осуществлять коннект с БД, как делать стандартные операциии [CRUD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD)
2. Более продвинутый уровень - изучите как работать с ORM (Object Relational Mapping) - в первую очередь с [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) - крайне условно: таблица БД - класс, а запись в таблице - объект.
3. Следующий уровень JPA - Java Persistence API - следующий уровень абстракции - надстройка над ORM - Hibernate - одна из реализаций JPA.

> Интересует что нужно изучить для того чтобы написать приложение, которое будет работать с БД (любым)?

Достаточно знания Hibernate

**Update**

Использование JDBC с Android является антипаттерном. У Android свои механизмы доступа к БД. Родным для Android ORM является [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Очень неплох универсальный ORM - [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) - одинаково успешно работает как под Android так и под desktop Java

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать

Comment: При написании андроид приложений и работе с sqlite БД я и так создаю классы, описывающие некие таблицы, а объекты класса используются для вставки, удаления, обновления записей в таблице.

Есть какие-нибудь русскоязычные ресурсы, по этому самому ORM и Hibernate? Желательно с примерами. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: См. апдейт ответа - остальное уже сами